# Unmounting an fabric panel in react (SPFX)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, spfx, office-fabric

[image: React developer screen Approval panel need removing ?]
So do I need to remove the  from the Dom ? If so how do I do this ? I have an  control on an SPFX Extension within SharePoint. The panel works fine and the props and the state is ok. when I click close the panel closes, but it doesn't trash the object - this means that the screen in the background remains grey.

I have used the react developer tools and I have been through all the states and I cannot find one that 'removes the component from the DOM' as such. I need the object completely going.

```
<Panel
headerText='Case Approval'
type={PanelType.medium}
onRenderFooterContent={this._onRenderFooterContent}
isOpen={this.state.showPanel}
isHiddenOnDismiss={this.state.hidden}
onDismiss={this._hidePanel}
focusTrapZoneProps={{}}
hasCloseButton = {this.state.hasCloseButton}>
```

Comment: When I press close, the background screen (main Sharepoint) goes dark grey and I cannot press anything or use Sharepoint, I have to refresh the browser before the screen goes clear again and I can use Sharepoint. So does the object need removing from the DOM ?

Comment: I have used isBlocking and set it to false and when I remove the panel the screen goes clear, but the object is still there and I cannot re-press the button to show the panel again... any ideas ?

Comment: any ideas anyone ? This is doing my head in!

Comment: are you able to solve this?

Comment: from what I remember , it was my react code... when I learnt more about react and how it all works then it just woked correctly.